# RSpec integration testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, rspec2

I have trouble with testing model count through feature/scenario rspec instrument

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Registration' do
  scenario 'Guest can sign up as individual' do
    with_role(:guest)
    sign_up(:client)
    Individual.count.should == 1
    # should be replaced by expect{ sign_up(:client) }.to change{ Individual.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```

How can I replace model.count should to the expect in the block to expecting in scenario? I don't want to use should because of record count changes every time I use it

Regards,
Alex

Comment: What are you asking for? What's wrong with that `expect`?

Comment: Why would calling `should` change the count?

Comment: phoet, it's don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of using the change matcher of rspec is as follows:

```
expect{ sign_up(:client) }.to change(Individual, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: Hm. I use this now, but it seems little complicated to use expect in scenario, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I really don't think so. It's much more expressive to document and reveal the intention of the spec. It is almost like fluent english. I like this form.